# Ubuntu 16.04 QBittorrent GUI stopped loading

Tags: gui, qbittorrent

Earlier today both web interface and GUI through VNClight would work. Now, the GUI through vncserver isn't showing. The webui still works and successfully downloads.

If I enter `qbittorrent` on a terminal, I get:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I enter the same on the VNCServer, I get:

```
Qt: XKEYBOARD extension not present on the X server.
```